# Another question about integrable functions with a transform

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, normed-spaces, lebesgue-measure

I am an engineering student, and taking a real analysis course at demand of my advisor, my inexperience in proofs is giving me hard time. I stumbled upon this example, whose proof left as an exercise. Could you please give me some clues? Here is the example:

$f\in L^1(\mathbb R^n).$ Show that
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow 1} \int_{\mathbb R^n}|f(x)-t^nf(tx)|\; dm=0
$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a lacunary solution.

1. Approximate $f$ in $\mathbb L^1$ by a simple function (a linear combination of characteristic functions of measurable sets: this reduced the proof where $f$ is such a function.
2. By linearity, do it when $f=\chi_B$, where $B$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb R^n$, with finite Lebesgue measure.
3. By outer regularity, we are reduced to threat the case $B$ open.
4. Use a dominated convergence argument.

Comment: Could you please more specific about steps?

Comment: Which step is problematic?

Comment: Ok you can show f as $\int\varphi\; dm$ and then $\sum a_k \chi_{\mathbb R^n}$, then I lose steps 2 and 3.

Comment: If you prove the result for $f=\chi_B$, we can handle the case $f=\sum_{i=1}^Nc_i\chi_{B_i}$, where $B_i$ are Borel subsets of finite measure and $c_i$^real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Make the problem easier by showing that, 
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x) - t_nf(t_nx)| \to 0 $$
Where $t_n$ is an sequence of real numbers converging to $1$.

This way you can then apply one of the convergence theorems.

Comment: $n\to\infty$? Can you write the absolute value expression as one $f_n$

Comment: Additionally how can I prove the integrability of the expression, before doing anything?